# Django + HTMX - create/update parent model with child models at once

Tags: django, htmx

I found a great tutorial about dynamically saving models in django using HTMX:

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVq_DjIfnBo
Text version: https://justdjango.com/blog/dynamic-forms-in-django-htmx

My problem is that I want to create author, add books and save author with books at once - using HTMX on one page.

Could you please explain, how to do it?
Thank you

Comment: You can create the author, save to db, then create the books (one at time) and save each one to the db.

Comment: You should look into django formsets and figure out how to generate proper html elements when adding new book, validation and edit etc The concept is very much the same other then you're just handing everything with ajax..

Answer (score 0):

first you have to create the 2 tables in the model.py with foreign key for the Author in Books table.

```
class Author(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID',primary_key=True)
Name = CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
Surname = CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'AUTHOR'


class Books(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID',primary_key=True)
Title = CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'BOOKS'
```

Create your forms.ModelForm in forms.py using the table books.
Thanks to the foreignkey with a select tag, you will have all the Authors at your disposal to choose one of them.

HTMX is doing the AJAX job, HTMX is sending the request to the server and sending back to the client the HTML for the "partial" page.

Hope this could be useful.